# ASP.NET How to Post a Master-Detail Views

Tags: model-view-controller

I need to post the data from an Order-Details Page..

I have a page with fields for Order Info.
Inside it is a user control for the Details Info.
New rows can be added to the details info.

Here are the fields:

### Order

Customer (textbox)
Order Date (textbox)

### Details(multiple)

Description (textbox)
Qty (textbox)
Price (textbox)
Amount (textbox)

When i click the Submit button. I need to get the
values of Order and Details and pass it in the controller.

How can i do this in MVC?

By the way, this is Create page.. so Order ID is not yet generated

Comment: Need to explain further.  What are you looking at posting back? just the master information? each individual detail? everything?

Comment: Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using MVC1, is there any reason that you don't just have the page strongly typed for the <Order>, and the usercontrol is a partial view strongly typed for a list of type <Detail>, and the usercontrol is invoked by passing the order id so that the appropriate details are returned and rendered by the partial view?